# Print Diamond Pattern using Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, io

I need to write a Haskell program that will generate a diamond output recursively.
Here is some sample output for given input

input : 1
output :

```
 *
* *
 *
```

input : 2
output :

```
    *
   * *
    *
 *     *
* *   * *
 *     *
    *
   * *
    *
```

input : 3 
output :

```
             *             
            * *             
             *              
          *     *           
         * *   * *          
          *     *           
             *              
            * *             
             *              

    *                 *    
   * *               * *   
    *                 *    
 *     *           *     * 
* *   * *         * *   * *
 *     *           *     * 
    *                 *    
   * *               * *   
    *                 *    
             *             
            * *             
             *              
          *     *           
         * *   * *          
          *     *           
             *              
            * *             
             *
```

I wrote following functions:

```
next 0 = [1,0,1]
next n = map (+3^n) (next (n-1)) ++ next (n-1) ++ map (+3^n) (next (n-1))
lpad n = map (++"*") (zipWith ($) (map (take)(next (n-1))) ((repeat(repeat ' '))))
pretty n = putStrLn $ intercalate "\n" $ lpad n
```

which gives following outputs:

pretty 1

```
 *
*
 *
```

pretty 2

```
    *
   *
    *
 *
*
 *
    *
   *
    *
```

Can anyone help me with the remaining halves? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was asked in an exam in PUCSD. (Pune university computer science department).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `n==0`, `next n` describes the whole picture up to mirroring. This is not the case anymore for greater `n`. So, in a first step, we change the `next` function to output a symmetric picture:

```
mmap = map . map

next :: Int -> [[Int]]
next 0 = [[1],[0,2],[1]]
next n = sn ++ map (\a -> a ++ map (+2*3^n) a) nn ++ sn
  where
    nn = next (n - 1)
    sn = mmap (+3^n) nn
```

Now, `next n` describes the positions of all stars. To print them, we first compute the relative distances.

```
diffs :: [Int] -> [Int]
diffs (x:xs) = x: diffs' x (xs)
  where
    diffs' x (y:ys) = y - x - 1 : diffs' y ys
    diffs' _ [] = []
diffs [] = []

lpad :: Int -> [[Char]]
lpad = map (concatMap $ \n -> replicate n ' ' ++ "*") . map diffs . next'
```

Applied to one line, `diffs` returns the list of the number of spaces we need to put before each star and `lpad` generates the picture from that. Print it as before:

```
pretty :: Int -> IO ()
pretty n = putStrLn $ unlines $ lpad n
```

Comment: This is a good solution to the problem as asked, and deserves more upvotes!

Answer (score 4):

I liked the task, so I wrote an alternative solution.

We could build it up, a bit like you would with a pretty printer. Look into the [pretty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty/) package to take these ideas and use them properly, but let's stick to plain old `[String]` for this.

First let's make a blank grid

```
blank :: Int -> [String]
blank n = replicate (3^n) $ replicate (3^n) ' '
```

Then let's define a diamond.

```
diamond :: Int -> [String]
diamond 0 = ["*"]
diamond n = let 
        o = diamond (n-1) 
        x = blank (n-1) in
    joinMatrix [[x,o,x]
               ,[o,x,o]
               ,[x,o,x]]
```

But how can we join this matrix of `[String]` together?
First get all the `String`s that should be concatenated together next to each other instead of under each other using `transpose`, then `concat` them all:

```
joinLine :: [[String]] -> [String]
joinLine = map concat.transpose
```

To do that to a whole matrix we need to join the lines on each row, then concat all the lines together into one list of lines:

```
joinMatrix :: [[[String]]] -> [String]
joinMatrix = concat.map joinLine
```

helper functions for printing:

```
put = mapM_ putStrLn
d n = put $ diamond n
```

You could argue that the numerical solution is more efficient, and it is, but `d 4` is the largest that fits on my screen and isn't slow. You could also argue that this solution is clearer.

```
*Main> d 0
*
*Main> d 1
 * 
* *
 * 
*Main>  d 2
    *    
   * *   
    *    
 *     * 
* *   * *
 *     * 
    *    
   * *   
    *
```

(It works for higher n too, but they would make this post unnecessarily long on the page.)

Comment: Don't forget to vote for cebewee's [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778632/print-diamond-pattern-using-haskell/13779048#13779048)!

Comment: Thanks :) I very much like how in your approach, you only need to encode the diamond once, whereas in my approach, there are two diamonds: Once in `next 0`, and once in `next n`.

Answer (score 1):

This is derived from AndrewC's solution. The space blocks are recursively generated and I prefer to use operators to make the code clearer:

```
diamond
    = putStr
    . unlines
    . fst
    . (iterate f (["*"], [" "]) !!)
  where
    f (d, e)
        = (  e + d + e
         ++  d + e + d
         ++  e + d + e
          ,  e + e + e
         ++  e + e + e
         ++  e + e + e
          )

    (+) = zipWith (++)
```

A generalization.
If we would like to have this:

```
             +             
            - -            
             +             
          -     -          
         + +   + +         
          -     -          
             +             
            - -            
             +             
    -                 -    
   + +               + +   
    -                 -    
 +     +           +     + 
- -   - -         - -   - -
 +     +           +     + 
    -                 -    
   + +               + +   
    -                 -    
             +             
            - -            
             +             
          -     -          
         + +   + +         
          -     -          
             +             
            - -            
             +
```

then the solution is `star 3` where

```
star
    = putStr
    . unlines
    . (\(d, p, e) -> d)
    . (iterate f (["-"], ["+"], [" "]) !!)
  where
    f (d, p, e)
        = (  e + p + e
         ++  d + e + d
         ++  e + p + e
          ,  e + d + e
         ++  p + e + p
         ++  e + d + e
          ,  e + e + e
         ++  e + e + e
         ++  e + e + e
          )

    (+) = zipWith (++)
```

Comment: I agree, infixes are great here. Though many programmers would not much like the shadowing of `+`, perhaps something like `%` would be better (default fixity `infixl 9` would in this case be equivalent to +'s `infixl 6`; and redeclaring it `infixr 6` (or `infixr 4`, for that matter) would actually make it a bit more efficient).

Comment: `%` is used in `Data.Ratio`. I don't mind shadowing for small examples like this.